# Benefits of hyperthreading for an Oracle database

Tags: oracle-database, hyperthreading

I'm running Oracle 10 on a blade450 g6. I have hyper-threading turned on but I have heard several people say that Oracle databases don't play well with it. Are there specific performance or reliability problems running an Oracle database with hyper-threading enabled?

Comment: hyper-threading is almost the same as having one more CPU for data-intensive applications, so I guess the performance for databases will increase significantly. As it is completely transparent to the application layer I don't see how it could affect reliability, unless there is some bug in the processor, so I guess you heard bullsht

Answer (score 2):

If Oracle has an official stance in their documentation, it is probably worth following that.  Alternatively you can benchmark it with HT on and off to determine which is better for your application.

For Intel CPUs, hyperthreading makes one physical core present itself as two logical cores to the OS.  The hardware is one physical core with certain components of the core duplicated while other components are shared.  Tasks that spend more time in the duplicated components will perform better with HT on and tasks that spend more time in the shared components will perform better with HT off.  There will also be performance issues based on your kernel scheduler (if it is old enough to be non-HT aware, it may not make efficient use of your cores) and cache issues if the logical cores are not working with similar memory regions as they share the L1 and L2 caches, which can cause each logical core to cause cache misses for the other.

Given the above issues, it is possible for HT to boost performance a modest 15-30% but it is also possible that it will decrease performance, but you'll most likely have to benchmark it yourself to know for sure.

Comment: I don't believe Oracle makes recommendations about HT. They do state that they support it. (For what it's worth, HT is enabled on Exadata database servers.)